# Out of memory Microsoft VBScript runtime error 800a0007

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0007'
>
> Out of memory: 'TheDB.Execute'
>
> page.asp, line 232

Database: Mysql

```vb
Public Sub SET_L(RAZA)
Flag=0         
sel = "SELECT id,unit,pindate FROM tbl_users where  id='" & RAZA & "' and pindate =NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY"
Set rs2 = TheDB.Execute(sel) <<--- line 232    
If Not rs2.EOF = True Then
Flag=1
LSD=LSD+rs2("unit")        
end if
End Sub

Public Sub SET_R(RAZA)
Flag=0         
sel = "SELECT id,unit,pindate FROM tbl_users where  id='" & RAZA & "' and pindate =NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY"
Set rs2 = TheDB.Execute(sel)     
If Not rs2.EOF = True Then
RSD=RSD+rs2("unit") 
end if        
End Sub
```

Unable to found out why.... :(

Comment: How are these procedures used in your ASP page, do they run in a loop etc? We have no visibility in the question how you use them, where does `RAZA` come from?, at the very least a [mcve] would help us understand better.

Comment: ya i have 1000000 row and looping this code

Comment: Wow, and you wonder why you get `Out of memory` errors?! So you are executing 1000000 queries *(doubt it would get that far before it falls over)* against the MySQL instance, that is **not** a good idea. I still don't understand though why you need a loop, I refer back to my original question, what does `RAZA` contain, where does it come from?

Comment: Please explain the _intent_ of this code.  It smells like a `COUNT(*)` would run a lot faster.

Comment: Not enough info for a conclusive answer but even of you solve the issue by putting more memory in the server, the approach is very primitive. You seem to be searching for records using a key (id) and summing a returned value. You should look to modify the SQL to have it do all the work. Going backwards and forwards to SQL for every row is going to be a vast overhead. Use SQL SUM instead.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I doubt they'd be able to add enough memory to make it run. Completely agree with this assessment, having SQL do the work is the best way to approach this. Running any kind of database execution inside a loop is a big no no.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to not properly closing recordset and connection objects and setting their references to nothing. Make sure this is done every time you use these objects:

```
myRecordset.close
myConnection.close
set myRecordset = nothing
set myConnection = nothing
```